# Change Intervals For a HighStock

Tags: highcharts

For a HighStock chart I want to create a bar chart that only shows a bar for every hour in a day and then when I switch to a week it shows only 7 bars (one for every day).  I know it would it involve the dataGrouping like so:

dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            units: [['hour',[1]]],
          },

Now I don't know how to put in 8 bars for a week or 12 bars for a year.

Comment: Have you tried to use two units? Instead of `[['hour',[1]]]`, use `[['hour',[1]], ['day', [1]]]` ?